# Will running a python script as admin cause all subprocesses to run with elevated rights?

Tags: windows-8.1, python, administrator, effective-permissions

I am on windows 8.1, python 3.

If I am using subprocess.run() to run a cmd command (particularly netsh export) and I run the python file as admin, will the command given to subprocess also be run as admin? (I have not specified any other argument)

If not, is it possible to do so by specifying any args of subprocess.run ?

Comment: Yes.  As a test, I suppose you can run: 
`cp = subprocess.run(["whoami","/all"])`  If you run Process Monitor you can see the process tree.

Comment: thx. if i run a python file by entering its name in an elevated cmd window, it will be executed as administrator right?

Comment: because i cant see "run as administrator" in options for py files, it only appears for executables

Comment: If the parent process is elevated then the child will be in this case.